# Append a NSString to a NSMutableString, raises an exception

Tags: objective-c

I access to a specific element of a NSMutableArray (nid) and save it in a NSString (num).

After that I want concatenate this element (num) with a url (NSMutableString), and use the method appendString but I obtain an exception.

how can I fix this?

below the code:

```c
NSMutableArray nid; 
....

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSString *num = [nid objectAtIndex:row];

NSMutableString *url = [[NSMutableString alloc]
                        initWithString:@"http://example.com/prova/"];

[url appendString:num];
```

Comment: what is the name of exception that you get ?

Comment: -[NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b54de0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b54de0'

Comment: how do you populate nid? Are you positive that `objectAtIndex:` is returning a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> -[NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b54de0
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x4b54de0'

As per the exception, it looks like `objectAtIndex:` is returning a `NSNumber` instead of a `NSString`. If `nid` contains numbers, you need to convert them to strings before you can pass them to `appendString`:

```
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSNumber *num = [nid objectAtIndex:row];
NSString *numStr = [num stringValue];

NSMutableString *url = [[NSMutableString alloc]
                        initWithString:@"http://example.com/prova/"];

[url appendString:numStr];

...

[url release];
```

Answer (score 1):

**nid**  is an `array` which  return an number not an NSString , so an NSNumber is being returned by the below statement

```
NSString *num = [nid objectAtIndex:row]; // Wrong statement 

NSNumber* num = [nid objectAtIndex:row]; // Correct statement
```

So your code should be ..

```
NSMutableArray nid; 
....

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

//your array contain NSNumber type of pointer NOT NSString.
NSNumber *num = [nid objectAtIndex:row];

//Get a NSString object from a NSNumber.
NSString *myString = [num stringValue];

NSMutableString *url = [[NSMutableString alloc]
                        initWithString:@"http://example.com/prova/"];

[url appendString:myString];
```

Comment: I'd probably just do `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/prova/%@", [nid objectAtIndex:row]]];`....

Comment: @ bbum: right , @reb2awrl: you could use as suggested by @ bbum.